# MySQL Read-only Replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I've multiple linux servers which runs MySQL server and my applicaiton each.

I have a cron job which creates daily backups and uploads them to another server. Daily backups are OK but, i want to be able to recover the current state of the database in case of the server goes down or whatever happens.

Can I create a single "read only async replication server" and configure all other servers to create replications to that server?

OR, what is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the version.

Look for "multi-source" replication.  This is where multiple Primaries can replicate to a single Replica.  But this does not say how you would restore a single Primary that dies.

Consider using a single Primary for everything, then have one (or more) Replicas.

Or you could have multiple Primary-Replica pairs sitting in VMs or Dockers.  The pair would, of course, have its parts on separate machines, preferably geographically separated (think storms, earthquakes, etc).